# Automatically Open a File when A certain directory is opened in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

Is it possible to open a certain text file or a file with specific extension, when I open a particular directory in Windows Explorer in Windows 10?

**Here is one possible scenario for this request:**
I conduct quarterly trainings. And I take/update notes regarding training response/important things to use/todos for next training. The problem is that I (as often) forget about those notes, by the time the next training comes up in few months. I do have a specific folder with all training materials.

So, is there a way to create some kind of scheduled task or automation, so that if I open this training folder, it automatically opens a specific file from that folder.

I understand, that I should be able "remember" this on my own. But let's face it, it is always a challenge to keep track of it, among many other things at work.

I have looked around, but could not find any solution. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Make a batch file that a) opens the file and b) opens Windows Explorer to a specific location. If you have multiple sets, e.g., four for each quarter-year, make four batch files. See https://askleo.com/open-windows-file-explorer-to-a-specific-folder/ for help.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik, thanks. However, I want some kind of process that opens the file, when I access a specific folder location in Windows explorer. I believe, it is little different that what you have suggested. Thanks.